# Merging titles after importing

Tags: r, dplyr

I have already imported tables in R from Excel. Below you can see how is look like data.

[image]

```
structure(list(English = c("English", "1", "2", "3", "4"), Citizenship = c("Citizenship", 
"Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Czechia", "Denmark"), `0-13` = c("Males", 
"3", "0", "0", "0"), ...4 = c("Females", "7", "0", "0", "0"), 
    ...5 = c("Unknown", "9", "0", "0", "0"), `14-17` = c("Males", 
    "9", "0", "0", "0"), ...7 = c("Females", "1", "0", "0", "0"
    ), ...8 = c("Unknown", "0", "0", "0", "0"), `18-34` = c("Males", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...10 = c("Females", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0"), ...11 = c("Unknown", "0", "0", "0", "0"), `35-64` = c("Males", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...13 = c("Females", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0"), ...14 = c("Unknown", "0", "0", "0", "0"), `65 and over` = c("Males", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...16 = c("Females", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0"), ...17 = c("Unknown", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Unknown = c("Males", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...19 = c("Females", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0"), ...20 = c("Unknown", "0", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

From the visual inspection of this table, you can see that the first three columns are imported good while columns number five and six have some dots ( e.g …4 and …5), and after that this is repeated until the end of the table. So in other words, we have columns that are good imported and columns that begin with dots.

So now I want to fix this problem and merge columns that are not well imported in this way (map, gsub or what is appropriate) example you can see below

```
Y_0-13_Males
Y_0-13_Females
Y_0-13_Unknown
```

I tried with this line but is not working

```
out <- out %>% mutate(pmap_df(., ~ na.locf0(c(...))))
colnames(out) <- gsub("\\.NA", "", paste(out[1,], out[2,], sep = "."))
```

So can anybody help how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you planning to do more analysis or is this the last step before presenting? If the former, I highly recommend reshaping the data into longer format with columns for Citizenship, Age, Gender, and Count. Forcing R to give multiple columns the same name may make later steps more unwieldy.

Comment: Here is a useful package related to this sort of problem: https://github.com/luisDVA/unheadr and related blog post: https://luisdva.github.io/rstats/merge-rows/

Comment: @JonSpring This is only importing of data. After that, I will continue with the analysis

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach: using `janitor` and `tidyverse` package with a mock example:

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(1:2)) %>% 
  mutate(value1 = rep(value[1:3], length.out = n())) %>% 
  group_by(english) %>% 
  mutate(name = paste(first(name), value1, sep = "_"), .keep="unused")  %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  slice(-1)
```

```
 english citizenship x_0_13_Males x_0_13_Females x_0_13_Unknown
  <chr>   <chr>       <chr>        <chr>          <chr>         
1 1       Belgium     3            7              9             
2 2       Bulgaria    0            0              0             
3 3       Czechia     0            0              0             
4 4       Denmark     0            0              0             
5 5       Germany     0            0              0
```

data:

```
structure(list(English = c("English", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
), Citizenship = c("citizenship", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Czechia", 
"Denmark", "Germany"), X.0.13. = c("Males", "3", "0", "0", "0", 
"0"), ...4 = c("Females", "7", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...5 = c("Unknown", 
"9", "0", "0", "0", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```